# Is there a non-IE equivalent of "all" element collection?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

When writing a javascript function to be executed in IE I can write something like

```
var myObj = document.getElementByID('myTable');
var firstRow = myObj.rows[0];
var allRowObjects = firstRow.all;
```

Outside of IE the ".all" won't be recognized so when running in other browsers I would run into a problem. I found reference to the querySelectorAll("*") function and that appears to be the environment safe way to get the same node list but is this what ".all" is doing? Is there a different analog that I should be using instead and where can I find documentation on "all"?

Comment: `firstRow.getElementsByTagName('*')`

Comment: That's because IE is great, other browsers suck!

Comment: @DaggNabbit - that should work, sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @adeneo it's an answer, but I'm too lazy to make it one. Here's a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) though. ;)

Comment: @adeneo :) looks like the first time I see a reason to say *IE is great*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft actually admits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that `.all` isn't part of any standard, is no longer supported beginning with IE 11, and suggests that you use `getElementById` instead.

> The all collection includes one element object for each valid HTML
>   tag. If a valid tag has a matching end tag, both tags are represented
>   by the same element object.
>
> The collection returned by the document's all collection always
>   includes a reference to the HTML, HEAD, and TITLE objects regardless
>   of whether the tags are present in the document.
>
> If the BODY tag is not present, but other HTML tags are, a BODY object
>   is added to the all collection. If the document contains invalid or
>   unknown tags, the collection includes one element object for each.
>   Unlike valid end tags, unknown end tags are represented by their own
>   element objects. The order of the element objects is the HTML source
>   order. Although the collection indicates the order of tags, it does
>   not indicate hierarchy.
>
> The name property only applies to some elements such as form elements.
>   If the vIndex is set to a string matching the value of a name property
>   in an element that the name property does not apply, then that element
>   will not be added to the collection.

Comment: Weird that they would suggest gEBI when it has totally different functionality.

Comment: Yeah it is a little strange, but then again this is MSFT's browser  we're talking about.